# CSRF_TOKEN not found even I mentioned it in meta tag

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to integrate `reactjs` with `laravel` . 
So What I did is , changed my js from `vue` to `react` by using some commands. 
Then I added `Example.js` file under `/resources/js/components` .
Then I added it in `app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('./components/Example');
```

my `Example.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">Example Component</div>

                            <div className="card-body">I'm an example component!</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Then I added a component of `Example.js` in my blade file.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class = "content">
    <div id = "Example" class = "title m-b-d">
    </div>
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/app.js"></script>
```

But I can't able to get the `Example.js` component in my blade file . 
In my console, I'm getting this error

> CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused probably by `bootstrap.js` (not laravel) which cannot find proper meta tag in header. Move your meta tag (with csrf token) from `<body>` to `<head>` - this should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. It worked . I missed to add it in my `header.blade.php` which contains the layout.